# Is there a way I can send a variable to a database from a form's action attribute value?

Tags: php

So I have a php file that retrieves some variables with the $_GET method and then outputs the result. I would want to send one of these retrieved variables to another php file (if it was possible to the same file would be fine also) through a form along with other variables which then are stored in a database. I tried putting the variable in the "action" attribute of the form like this but it didn't appear in the url when I submitted the form values:

Here is all my code:

```
<?php 
$nome=$_GET[nome];
$cognome=$_GET[cognome];
echo "<form action='salva_citazione.php"."?autore=".$nome."+".$cognome."&' method='GET'>"
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hidden input fields, also you forgot to use `'` in your `$_GET` variables:

```
<?php 
  $nome = htmlspecialchars($_GET['nome']);
  $cognome = htmlspecialchars($_GET['cognome']);
  $fullname  = $nome.' '.$cognome;

  echo '<form action="salva_citazione.php" method="GET">';
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="autore" value="'.$fullname.'" />';
  // ...
?>
```

Note that this way of using `$_GET` results in XSS vulnerabilities, so I've used [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function to convert special characters to HTML entities.

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside the form:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='autore' value='$nome+$cognome'/>";
```